# Problem with R. in android project

Tags: android

I did a clean on my android project and now a bunch of R.thisandthat are showing up as errors.

I cannot figure out what went wrong here.

Please help./

Comment: Without the errors (and some of the resource files), it's guess work...

Comment: You should post then the solution you've got, and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cleaning your project you will have to give refresh too for generating the `gen` files.

Answer (score 2):

So I think this is an ADT problem I have found too. In the latest versions there was a "feature" that was advertised that didn't require aapt to run during all builds (in previous versions it ran with all builds, incremental builds were loooooong because of this). However I found it doesn't run at all after a clean. So I end up just selecting the project in the package explorer after a clean build and hitting refresh. This forced aapt to run and generate a new R class. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice idea... at least it beats restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

when u clean the project and build again it may import android.R to your application.delete that import statement.hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had the same problem too , Right clicked on Project in Project explorer >>Properties >>> Android(From Left List) >> Choose API (if You have newer then choose it) >> Apply >>> Ok

Now Clean Again The project! it should be fine

Dont import R file in your classes